# Create normalized Pandas dataframe from nested json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been reading this post: [Create normalized dataframe from a nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76838992/create-normalized-dataframe-from-a-nested-json) ...and need to ask my own questions since I am doing the same thing but I think my json is more difficult.  In the end I want to extract what I capture into an email.

We have a vendor who created a new version 2 of their API and now we have to make changes to our Production ETL code.

Their new API is not well documented so I'm having to make do.  I need to pull warning from json data nested four deep in the json schema of lists and dictionaries.  I have to go through dictionaries of data, attributes, result, before I reach warnings and then get lists of terms, teachers, courses, and enrollments which may contain warnings or may be empty.

Posted below is the full json response.

```
{
    "data":{
        "id":"12345",
        "type":"file_import",
        "attributes":{
            "id":"12345",
            "type":"Academics API",
            "dry_run":true,
            "status":"completed",
            "import_started_at":"2023-08-08T22:24:02.998Z",
            "import_completed_at":"2023-08-08T22:24:03.065Z",
            "result":{
                "info":{
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":{
                        "created":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[]
                        },
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[]
                        }
                    },
                    "courses":{
                        "created":{
                            "total":1,
                            "list":[
                                "Course:  - Section: "
                            ]
                        },
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[]
                        }
                    },
                    "enrollments":{
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0
                        },
                        "students":{
                            "updated":{
                                "total":0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "warnings":{
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":[
                        {
                            "type":"general",
                            "message":"No teachers information has been found during the import.",
                            "list":[]
                        }
                    ],
                    "courses":[],
                    "enrollments":[
                        {
                            "type":"missing_students",
                            "message":"The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.",
                            "list":[
                                "E",
                                "r",
                                "o"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "errors":{
                    "general":[],
                    "original_data":[],
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":[],
                    "courses":[],
                    "enrollments":[]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The id represents the get request to check the status of the import. The meat and potatoes begin down in warnings which is as I said full of lists such as terms, teachers, courses, and enrollments.  I assume each will have their own type, message, and list. How do I burrow down to even check if I have any warning at all?  Then, if there are warnings present capture them in a Pandas dataframe for easy reporting.

I was starting with something like so, but I don't think it's very elegant.

```
jd = getSync.json()
 with open("output.json", mode="w") as fh:
            json.dump(jd, fh, indent=4, separators=(",", ":"))
        warnings = False
        if jd["data"]:
            if jd["data"]["attributes"]:
                if jd["data"]["attributes"]["result"]:
                    if jd["data"]["attributes"]["result"]["warnings"]:
                        warnings = True

data_df = pd.json_normalize(data,
                                    meta=["type", "message", "list", ["E", "r", "o"]],
                                    record_path=["list"],
                                    record_prefix="list.",
                                    )
```

Here is what the dataframe should look like.

```
warnings        warning.type        warnings.message                                                                        warnings.list   
terms           missing_terms       The following terms were not found...                                                   Spring 2021             
terms           missing_terms       The following terms were not found...                                                   Spring 2022             
teachers        general             No teachers information has been found during the import.   
courses         general             Don't have an example of this mesage
enrollments     missing_students    The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.   E
enrollments     missing_students    The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.   r
enrollments     missing_students    The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.   o
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there how the output dataframe should look like?

Comment: how did you define `data`?

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't match the sample data exactly so this is my best guess:

Data:

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "id": "12345",
        "type": "file_import",
        "attributes": {
            "id": "12345",
            "type": "Academics API",
            "dry_run": True,
            "status": "completed",
            "import_started_at": "2023-08-08T22:24:02.998Z",
            "import_completed_at": "2023-08-08T22:24:03.065Z",
            "result": {
                "info": {
                    "terms": [],
                    "teachers": {
                        "created": {
                            "total": 0,
                            "list": []
                        },
                        "updated": {
                            "total": 0,
                            "list": []
                        }
                    },
                    "courses": {
                        "created": {
                            "total": 1,
                            "list": [
                                "Course:  - Section: "
                            ]
                        },
                        "updated": {
                            "total": 0,
                            "list": []
                        }
                    },
                    "enrollments": {
                        "updated": {
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "students": {
                            "updated": {
                                "total": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "warnings": {
                    "terms": [],
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "type": "general",
                            "message": "No teachers information has been found during the import.",
                            "list": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "courses": [],
                    "enrollments": [
                        {
                            "type": "missing_students",
                            "message": "The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.",
                            "list": [
                                "E",
                                "r",
                                "o"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "errors": {
                    "general": [],
                    "original_data": [],
                    "terms": [],
                    "teachers": [],
                    "courses": [],
                    "enrollments": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
df = (pd
      .DataFrame(data=data.get("data").get("attributes").get("result"))
      .explode(column="warnings").explode(column="info")
      )
df = (pd
      .concat([df, df.pop("warnings").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
      .drop(columns=0)
      .fillna("")
      .reset_index(names="warnings")
      )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        warnings      info errors              type                                                                                message       list
0          terms               []                                                                                                                    
1       teachers   created     []           general                              No teachers information has been found during the import.         []
2       teachers   updated     []           general                              No teachers information has been found during the import.         []
3        courses   created     []                                                                                                                    
4        courses   updated     []                                                                                                                    
5    enrollments   updated     []  missing_students  The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.  [E, r, o]
6    enrollments  students     []  missing_students  The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.  [E, r, o]
7        general               []                                                                                                                    
8  original_data               []
```